# Rails 4 + Mongoid not able to query with created_at field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a Utility collection. In the model i have added a created_at instance method.

I want to query the collection for records created_at previous day.

Eg. `Utility.where(:created_at.gte => yesterday, :created_at.lt => today)`

but i get empty array even if record with created_at.gte yesterday is present.

eg.

```
t = Utility.first.created_at
=> 2015-04-20 14:15:08 +0530

t = Utility.first.created_at.utc
=> 2015-04-20 08:45:08 UTC

Utility.where(:created_at.gte => t)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"created_at"=>{"$gte"=>2015-04-20 08:45:08 UTC}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Utility
  embedded: false>

Utility.where(:created_at.gte => t).count
=> 0
```

I can't figure it out why i am not getting the records that satify the condition. I am new to mongodb and mongoid. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3590) ?

Comment: thanks anthony, mine is the same issue.